# Mixed DML and a future method cannot call Other Future

Tags: apex, trigger, future

I have two objects `Roster_Details__c` (Custom Object) and `User` (Standard Object). Now the requirement is when I insert a record in roster details, a corresponding user must be created and a field (lookup on user) in roster details record must be updated.
For the trigger on roster_details, to insert user, `userInserter()` function is placed in `future` method (to avoid mixed DML). Now to update the roster_detail record back, I cannot update roster_details directly because of the Mixed DML issue and also `roster_detailsUpserter()` function cannot be placed in future method because `userInserter()` is already a future method.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: You cannot call `future` method from trigger. That's a known limitation.

Comment: @RohitMourya I have the future method in another class,which the trigger calls from. So that's not a limitation. For example:
`code`
trigger EventAfterUpdate on Event (After Insert) {
           
              for(Event event:Trigger.new){
                       class.methode() //futur method
              }
             
}
class {
 @future
              public method(){
                  //your custom logic
              }
}
`code`

Comment: Yes. but ideally you should use invocable method which implemets `Queueable` interface. And from that you can call `future` method. This can prevent the error which you're getting.

Comment: @RohitMourya `@future` methods can be called from triggers. Also, `Queueable` is just a different way of running code asynchronously. If you're simply trying to avoid mixed DML (as the OP is), then there is no need to call an `@future` method from code being executed async from the flex queue.